# using Python to process and generate Excel files

Tags: python, excel, vba

Wondering if Python has free and reliable library to read Excel file, manipulate data and generate Excel file output, just like VBA did? My current problem is, the project has both Python and VBA code, I am trying to see if I can use single programming language to make it simple. Thanks.

Using Python 2.7.

regards,
Lin

Comment: This site has a decent breakdown of the options: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @tknickman, I do not know that yet, awesome and vote up. Do you think to process Excel file, Python could do almost all VBA did, so that I can complete replace VBA? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/)

I used it for creating basic Excel reports for business teams, and it has been a pleasure to use. :-)

Comment: Thanks kkaosninja, vote up. :) Pivot table also supported?

Comment: @LinMa Sorry. I don't think Pivot tables are supported.

Comment: Thanks kkaosninja, do you think I can write data in Excel and then building pivot table in Excel manually using the data written by openpyxl?

Comment: Yes @LinMa. That is very much possible. Reading and writing from Excel files is extremely easy using ```openpyxl```. In fact, I was able to port all my PHP reporting scripts(using PHPExcel) to Python because of it. :-D

Comment: Thanks kkaosninja, awesome. Some of my Excel file has size around 50-100M bytes, do you think openpyxl could handle it well? :)

Comment: My experience has mostly been writing to files. ```openpyxl``` has an optimized write-only mode for that. Similarly an optimized read-only mode exists as well => https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/optimized.html, which I think you will come in handy for you.

Comment: Hi kkaosninja, thanks for all the help and mark your reply as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I either use openpyxl or the pywin32 COM interface directly.
openpyxl is very fast as it manipulates data directly in the excel file on disk, where as the pywin32 com interface uses Excel itself, with the python code mimicking what VBA does.

The main difference between the two is that openpxl only gives you a subset of commands, so great for pulling data out of an excel file to use elsewhere or building a new excel file from existing data. However to get the full functionality you need to use the COM interface.

This [site](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/) gives a good intro to using the COM interface. One thing to watch out for is the constants that are scattered throughout the COM interface calls. You generally need to find out those values yourself, you can start by looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff197824(v=office.14).aspx)

Finally you can also take a look at IronPython which is a .NET implementation of python which gives a cleaner interface but isn't actually vanilla python (and not cross-platform), so maybe not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Matt, awesome and vote up. Some of my Excel file has size around 50-100M bytes (for both read and write), do you think openpyxl could handle it well? :)

Comment: Honestly I've never tried with files that big (maybe up to 10MB). I think openpxl could probably handle it. The xlsx file format is a zipped up series of XML files, it will depend a little on the data that is store in the file itself and will as much depend on the amount of RAM you have available on your machine as anything else. Opening and editing a file is only a few lines of code, so best to give it a go and see :)

Comment: Thanks Matt, vote up. It seems pivot table is not supported?